# CVE-2014-0196 and grs kernel

Tags: kernel, security

my client is renting a server in OVH.
Everyone knows about OVH and their default kernel from GRS ((

Can anybody say if the kernel 3.2.13-grsec-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64  is affected to CVE-2014-0196 (not openssl!!) or where I can find more info about this magic kernel?
Thank YOU!

Comment: Yes your kernel is affected as grsec is a patch . In theory, grsec might stop the vulnerability, depends on what you compiled and configured. You can ask on the grsec mailing list if you wish to know for certain. grsec is , however, not in the ubutnu repositories and I am going to guess support for grsec is limited at best here. Most people on Ubuntu use Apparmor (rather then grsec) and I am going to guess there is limited experience with that patch here. You might ask in #gentoo

Answer (score 2):

not sure if grsec was vulnerable in the first place, but they did backport the patch for it, so you might be better off updating your kernel.

http://grsecurity.net/changelog-test.txt

```
commit 4f0228bf02504dc03b8230f0463677e23fdf1978
Author: Brad Spengler <spender@grsecurity.net>
Date: Mon May 5 18:12:30 2014 -0400
 Backport fix for heap overflow in the tty layer, CVE-2014-0196
 http://bugzillafiles.novell.org/attachment.cgi?id=588355
```